# How can I configure DisplayFusion so that DisplayFusion taskbars are in the same order than the Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows, taskbar, displayfusion

Windows 7 cannot natively display a taskbar to each of my monitors, so I use [DisplayFusion's multi-taskbars feature](http://www.displayfusion.com/Features/Taskbar/). How can I configure DisplayFusion so that the applications in the DisplayFusion taskbars are in the same order than the applications in the the Windows taskbar?

DisplayFusion taskbars:

[image]

Windows taskbar:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DisplayFusion can't do this natively (yet), but you can drag/drop re-order the buttons on the DisplayFusion taskbars. This is a bit of a manual process, but once you have the order set, new windows would be added to the right-side like on the Windows taskbar. Mirroring the taskbar button order is planned for a future DisplayFusion version.

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer of DisplayFusion*

Comment: Thanks, looking forward the implementation! With a 4-line taskbar as you can imagine it's pretty painful :)

Comment: The hard part about this feature is that each version of Windows makes it more difficult to query the taskbar button order. We have it planned though.  :)